# Prase error ther was a probleme prasing the package

Tags: android, sdk, installation, apk

I try to send an .apk from server to my device (emulator and tablet), and I install it like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/data/com.so.and/s.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In the emulator I have this error: Parse error there was a problem parsing the package.

On my tablet the error is: un probléme est survenu lors de l'analyse du kit (a problem occurred during the analysis kit).

Comment: Are you using `"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in your launch Activity?

Comment: try using original device . The error you are getting is from the following line I guess 
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/data/data/com.so.and/s.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

Comment: is't a problem for target?, initialy it works but not now . "android:theme" in xml to my activity. original device?

Comment: Sorry I mean real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by many problems:

1. incompatible SDK
2. error in path
3. you don't have permission to launch your file.apk, for example if you are in data/data/com.exemple.app
4. go to setting security check source unknown
5. damage file when you make your download (retry)